# How to validate an oAuth 2.0 access token in oWin?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, jwt

We are building a SPA frontend app connected to multiple ASP.Net WebAPI services. We want to use oAuth2.0 for authentication. After authenticating we want to use the information in the token to find related information in our database.

When we implement the Authentication Server ourselved, we control the format and encryption of the access token. That works fine. We can validate these tokens.

But now we want to use external OAuth2.0 authentication services, such as Microsoft and Google. In OWin one can turn these services on in the Startup class. But how can we validate the access tokens returned by these services? What is their generic format? How do we know the encoding/encryption/signing?

Comment: encoding/encryption/signing of what?  It's just an opaque token, you could use it as a "key"; but that's about all you can use it for.

Comment: Several people mention that one needs to do a validation of the token. See for example: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatinganidtoken. Maybe I am mixing things up here.

Comment: That is not an access token, that is an id token and isn't part of oauth, it's part of openid

Comment: @Rine I am stuck at authenticating or validating access token at resource server. I am sending the clientid in an encrypted format from the authorization server to the Client app. From client app, the request comes with the encrypted access token and i have to authenticate the request at resource server. For authentication i will decrypt the access token and then retrieve the clientid for authentication. I tried custom OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider, but it didn't work. Validate identity function was not called during request.